# ThreadPoolExecutor causes hangs in Pyspark pools

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor from `concurrent.futures` in Python to apply concurrency to my Pyspark job. But I see that usually when I have some tasks having heavy Read or Broadcast Joins in Pyspark, the ThreadPool just hangs. The Spark UI seems to hang indefinitely!

Could anyone help me with handling this issue?

Also , If someone can show me how to use ProcessPool instead of Threadpool in Pyspark would be helpful. When I try to do so, I'm getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Studies\Python\multiprocessing1.py", line 13, in <module>
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 136, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 198, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 306, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2483)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2479)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2479)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.markPartiallyConstructed(SparkContext.scala:2568)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Studies/Python/multiprocessing1.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Studies/Python/multiprocessing1.py", line 57, in main
    print('Result: ', _.result())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 428, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

The code for the above error is :

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import threading
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import findspark
import time
import concurrent.futures
findspark.init()

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster(
    'local').set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
thread_local = threading.local()

arr = ["A", "B", "C"]


def test(a):
    z = ("NA", "NA")

    if a == "A":
        sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", a)
        print("thread A started at " + str(time.time()))
        range100 = spark.range(100)
        count100 = range100.count()
        z = (a, str(count100))
    elif a == "B":

        sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", a)
        print("thread B started at " + str(time.time()))
        range200 = spark.range(100000)
        count200 = range200.count()
        z = (a, str(count200))
    elif a == "C":
        sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", a)
        print("thread C started at " + str(time.time()))
        range300 = spark.range(300)
        count300 = range300.count()
        z = (a, str(count300))
    print("thread {} ended at ".format(a) + str(time.time()))
    sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", None)
    return z


start_time = time.time()
result = []
# for i in arr:
#     result.append(test(i))
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # result = executor.map(test, arr)
    result_futures = list(map(lambda x: executor.submit(test, x), arr))
    # result = [Row(f.result())
    #           for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_futures)]
    for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_futures):
        print('Result: ', _.result())
        result.append(_.result())

# print(result)
result_df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(result).toDF()
print(result_df.show())
print(start_time-time.time())
# result = p.map(test, arr)
# p.close()
# p.join()
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing same issue with ProcessPoolExecutor, but when I use ThreadPoolExecutor, it runs fine